# How to add variation to a game on Arena Chess?

Tags: arena

Suppose I load a game from PGN on arena. Check screenshot.

[image]

If I want to add a variation to a main move, how can I do it? Is there any option to add a variation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the move where you want to insert a variation and make an alternative. Then, a popup will open:

[image]

- New variation will create a new variation (what you actually want).
- Overwrite will overwrite the main move and all the next moves.

If you want to make a variation mainline, then right-click one of its moves → Upgrade variation.

Note: This works as long as your "Default action for adding moves" is set to "Always ask". If Arena isn't working this way for you, then right-click on the move list. This will bring up a menu where you can set this option.